# Bleed port repair on Shimano road brake lever?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

I noticed that a small amount of mineral oil had leaked from the bleed port on my Shimano road brake lever. I inspected the bleed port screw and saw that it was loose. The threads on the lever appeared to be damaged. The threads on the bolt ("Y0C698030") appear to be fine.

I was able to screw the bolt back in, pumped the lever a few times and it seemed to stay put. No further mineral oil leaked and the braking does not feel spongy.

However, now I'm not sure what to do:

- Is the brake safe to use?
- Can I repair the thread, perhaps with a helicoil or threaded insert? If so, what are the dimensions?
- Do I need to replace the entire shifter?
- Should I make a warranty claim with Shimano?

---

Here is the brake/shifter diagram for clarity:

[image: Assembly diagram with the bleed port screw highlighted]

Comment: Any idea how the threads got damaged? Was the bolt cross threaded in the past?

Comment: I don't know, although cross-threading is plausible

Comment: The diagramm shows the brand new GRX levers. Is that what you have? In that case it cannot be older than a few months.

Comment: @gschenk yes indeed. I wasn't expecting any trouble

Comment: Check your other lever's bleed port - is there supposed to be a small O ring?

Comment: @Criggie There is an o-ring on both levers

Comment: Check the thread for any signs of cross threading. If there  are no signs of it I would definitely try and claim warranty for the issue. If it was indeed cross threaded I think it's unlikely that Shimano will cover the costs..

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem in Shimano 105 road shifter. I solve it by wrapping bleed screw with PTFE pipe tape and it did tightened to damaged threads in bleeding port.

Comment: Welcome to bicycles.stackexchange.com!  It's always great to hear first-hand reports of solutions to problems.

Comment: Although PTFE / Teflon tape will help and aid in sealing threads, brake fluid over time will dissolve the tape, so although everything seems good at the mo you may need to revisit the threads at a later stage

Comment: @DanK Just saw this comment. I assume DOT fluid could dissolve Teflon tape. Shimano uses mineral oil. I have a hunch it won't dissolve Teflon tape, but do you have different experience?

Answer (score 7):

I would re-tighten the bleed port screw and watch for leaks. If you get no leakage and the screw does not loosen then you are fine.

A partially damaged thread should not be a problem as the bleed port screw does not have any load on it. (There should not even be any fluid pressure on it during braking as the reservoir is cut off from the line by the piston when the lever is pulled.)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Shimano GRX leaver - just found that mineral oil leaked (a spot of leaking oil is visible). bleed screw can not be screwed in (it simply scrolls in the thread). The thread exists in the port by the way.
[image: shimano Bleed Screw & O-Ring thread problem]

[image: Bleed screw]

[image: there is a thread inside the port]

Thinking now how to fix such problem. For now I have next solutions on my mind:

1. add mineral oil in the oil tank, put the bleed screw in the
   thread and use PTFE pipe tape to fix it as answered above - dont
   know how effectively this way should be
2. bore the hole of the bleed screw port on the leaver and use a bolt with o-ring with bigger size -- also dont know if that a good way
3. change the leaver

A bit disappoint because of getting new bike with such small but possibly costly bug of the leaver. I will update the answer with my final solution later.

Comment: It is frustrating how Shimano used such weak threads for this critical (and expensive) component. Many people are having this issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  I agree the problem is frustrating, but I'm afraid that "I'm having this problem too" doesn't really answer the question.  Please only post answers that answer the question; you should read [answer] and take the [tour] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: yep. thank u. updated the answer with possible solutions on my mind. also I'll update my final decision on that problem a bit later (when i fix it).

Comment: Shimano honors their warranty. If it's a new bike you bought, just go that route. Don't go trying to hack the lever to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with shimano GRX 810 lever. firstly, determine whether issue is lever or screw. Does the funnel adapter still screw in? if yes, you may have to butcher an adapter then use a bung in its fill hole, after all the the bleed screw in effect is only a removable bung. you may be able to tap a thread for a nylon bolt etc into the butchered funnel adapter. If the issue is with the screw replace with part no Y0C698030 from sjs cycles. Alternatively you could try a tiny dental band on the screw thread to help form a seal in the lever hole effectively rendering it a bung & not a screw.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?  What, specifically, turned out to be the problem, and how did you fix it?  Did your fix last?

Answer (score 1):

I found a small cork and put it in the hole and this seems to be working.  I can easily get it out using a pair of needle nosed pliers and by turning it (like I was removing a screw).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My partners bike has this issue! The r8025 levers oil bleed thread,  on her giant disc Liv has been threaded! Annoyingly, it was most likely done by trek, where we bought the bike last year, as it came pre assembled!

We reached out to them, but as it's after 12 months (month 13...) They have said it's out of warranty!
We have 2 options from what I can see...

1. suck up the cost and buy a new lever, circa £200
2. somehow re-thread the plastic part of the oil bleed port.

In line with re-threading...did you guys have any luck with this? I was thinking maybe trying something along these lines ...
https://amzn.eu/d/7g4vFf3

If I could fit the thread insert into the plastic body, and the bleed cup & bolt still worked, would this be an issue?

I am thinking that as long as it's sealed for pressurising when the break is pulled,.theres not other integral reason this wouldn't work?

Although I'm happy to be correct, or for any other suggestions!!

Alex

Comment: Welcome to bicycle’s exchange. This appears to be a new question, not an answer to the original question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/55896)